# SystemExit and NameError issues with exiting

Tags: python, exit

```
def main():
    try:
        print "hardfart"
        return 0
    except:
        return 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    exit(main())
```

Can one kind programmer tell me why this spits out the following error on exit?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Apps/exp_exit.py", line 9, in ,module.
exit(main())
File "C:\Apps\python2.7.2\lib\site.py", line 372 in __call__
    raise SystemExit(code)
SystemExit: 0
```

This is causing an error on exit in a project that's set up similarly. For that project, after using gui2exe to compile an exe, when closing the program I get this related error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "checkHDBox.py", line 303, in <module>
NameError: name 'exit' is not defined
```

So if exit is generating this error, how do I exit then?  And if I create an exception handler for exit, doesn't that replace the default action that python takes with the exit function?

Thanks.

Edit:

I think this answers my own question.

The traceback here is from IDLE, I think it's a default behavior from other sources I've read.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Apps/exp_exit.py", line 9, in ,module.
exit(main())
File "C:\Apps\python2.7.2\lib\site.py", line 372 in __call__
    raise SystemExit(code)
SystemExit: 0
```

The traceback here was fixed by using sys.exit() instead of exit(0)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "checkHDBox.py", line 303, in <module>
NameError: name 'exit' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

You exit a program by raising `SystemExit`. This is what `exit()` does. Someone has incorrectly written an exception handler that catches all exceptions. **This is why you only catch the exceptions you can handle.**

Comment: Scratch that. This traceback comes from IDLE, do you know if that is intended functionality for it to bring that traceback up on any exit call?